# Text area white spaces in form

Tags: javascript, jquery, liferay

I have one form in with textarea:

```
<textarea wrap="physical" cols="28" rows="5" name="<portlet:namespace />tsSummary" onKeyDown="CountRight(this.form.<portlet:namespace />tsSummary,this.form.right,200);getElementById('char_count_summary').innerHTML = this.value.length" onKeyUp="CountRight(this.form.<portlet:namespace />tsSummary,this.form.right,200);getElementById('char_count_summary').innerHTML = this.value.length" onfocus="getElementById('char_count_summary').innerHTML = this.value.length">
                    <c:choose><c:when test="<%=Validator.isNotNull(dMang)%>"><%=dMang.getTsSummary()%></c:when><c:otherwise><%=""%></c:otherwise></c:choose>
            </textarea>
                <b><span id=char_count_summary></span></b>
                <input readonly type="hidden" name="right" size=3 maxlength=3>
```

Javascript for limiting count to 200:

```
function CountRight(field, count, max) {
        // if the length of the string in the input field is greater than the max value, trim it
        if (field.value.length > max)
        field.value = field.value.substring(0, max);
        else
        // calculate the remaining characters
        count.value = max - field.value.length;
    }
```

But, I get extra leading white spaces whenever i open the form and it takes extra characters showing count more than 200.
How can I remove extra blank spaces before content?

Answer (score 3):

Remove the spaces in the source from between `<textarea …>` and `<c:choose>`

Answer (score 0):

```
function trim(value) {
  value = value.replace(/^\s+/,''); 
  value = value.replace(/\s+$/,'');
  return value;
}
```

this removes any whitespace on the start or end of a string. You could do something like

```
field.value = trim(field.value);
```